# Foreach Loop acting different for the first item

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have a forEach loop in Ejs format, that takes an array and generates a form for each item then handled in the back-end with node when submitted. However, for the first item in the array it skips the form, and just generates the contents inside the form hence the buttons don't work since they can't be posted. The loop looks like this:

```
<div class="my-chains">
        <%userChains.forEach(function(chain, index) { %>
        <div class="chain-item">
        <form id="chain-display" action="/chainDisplay" method="POST">
        <h5 class="chain-header"><span><%=chain.chainName%></span><span> (Current Streak: <strong><%=chain.streak%></strong> days)</span></h5>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="decrease"><i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></button> 
          <button type="submit" name="submit" value="increase"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
          <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="<%=chain.chainName%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="currentId" value="<%=chain._id%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="currentStreak" value="<%=chain.streak%>">
          <span>
            <%for(i=0; i<chain.streak; i++){%>
              <i class="fa-solid fa-trophy"></i>
            <%}%>
          </span>
          </form>
        </div>
            <%});%>
      </div>
```

I put 2 objects in that array as an example, and this is how they're generated. (See they're exactly the same thing but first one is not wrapped in the form tags, I cannot figure out why). Any subsequent object I add into the array comes out fine. Just the first one doesn't have the form tags. Thank you for your help in advance.

[image: Generated by foreach loop]

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure what you mean, I have 2 form id's and they're different. But just to make sure I removed them but its still the same. First item generated by forEach is not wrapped in the form for some reason :(

Comment: `<form id="chain-display" ...` - There's nothing unique/dynamic with that id. Each `<form>` has the same id: `chain-display`

Comment: I somehow fixed it, the inside form was wrapped by the outer one, I separated them and now it works. No idea why but hey it works.

Comment: @Andreas oh you're right didn't think about it! Even though that wasn't the issue your advice is useful. Thank you!